# Correct Model Specific Register (MSR) to check turbo boost for different Intel CPU models?

Tags: linux, intel

I manage the following servers (but not limited to) for my work:

```
Coffee Lake: E-2146G, E-2276G, E-2286G, E-2146G, E-2276G
Kaby Lake: E3-1230 v6, E3-1230 v6
Haswell: E3-1231 v3
```

I referenced the Intel manual to check what MSR I can use to check if turbo boost is enabled or not for a given server:

Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Combined Volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D, 3A, 3B, 3C, 3D, and 4
https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671200
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html (use this link if the download link doesn't work)

And the following terminal output is from a server that uses E3-1230 v6 @ 3.50GHz (Kaby Lake) CPU.

```
root@dse-seo-001:~> rdmsr -a 0x1A0 -f 38:38
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


root@dse-seo-001:~> turbostat -c 0-7 --quiet -i 1
Core CPU Avg_MHz Busy% Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IPC IRQ SMI POLL C1 POLL% C1% CPU%c1 CPU%c3 CPU%c6 CPU%c7 CoreTmp PkgTmp Totl%C0 Any%C0 GFX%C0 CPUGFX% SYS%LPI PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt PKG_% RAM_%
- - 84 2.39 3500 3504 3.18 632 0 7 667 0.02 97.62 97.61 0.00 0.00 0.00 32 32 19.13 18.44 0.00 0.00 0.00 7.81 4.94 0.00 1.75 0.00 0.00
0 0 4 0.11 3500 3504 0.56 25 0 0 38 0.00 99.89 99.89 0.00 0.00 0.00 32 32 19.13 18.44 0.00 0.00 0.00 7.81 4.94 0.00 1.75 0.00 0.00
0 4 10 0.29 3500 3504 0.80 71 0 0 87 0.00 99.72 99.71
1 1 7 0.19 3500 3504 0.70 44 0 1 61 0.03 99.81 99.81 0.00 0.00 0.00 32
1 5 6 0.17 3500 3504 0.52 81 0 1 105 0.03 99.84 99.83
2 2 8 0.21 3500 3504 0.70 187 0 2 195 0.03 99.80 99.79 0.00 0.00 0.00 30
2 6 3 0.07 3500 3504 0.39 28 0 1 38 0.03 99.93 99.93
3 3 5 0.15 3500 3504 0.50 89 0 1 100 0.03 99.85 99.85 0.00 0.00 0.00 32
3 7 628 17.93 3500 3504 3.35 107 0 1 43 0.03 82.07 82.07


root@dse-seo-001:~> lscpu
Architecture: x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order: Little Endian
Address sizes: 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s): 8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 4
Socket(s): 1
NUMA node(s): 1
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
CPU family: 6
Model: 158
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 v6 @ 3.50GHz
Stepping: 9
CPU MHz: 3500.000
CPU max MHz: 3500.0000
CPU min MHz: 800.0000
BogoMIPS: 6999.82
Virtualization: VT-x
L1d cache: 128 KiB
L1i cache: 128 KiB
L2 cache: 1 MiB
L3 cache: 8 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s): 0-7
Vulnerability Gather data sampling: Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Itlb multihit: KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
Vulnerability L1tf: Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Mds: Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown: Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Mmio stale data: Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Retbleed: Mitigation; IBRS
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1: Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2: Mitigation; IBRS, IBPB conditional, STIBP conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
Vulnerability Srbds: Mitigation; Microcode
Vulnerability Tsx async abort: Mitigation; TSX disabled
Flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good n
opl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f
16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rds
eed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

However, based on `turbostat`'s reading and my CPU's basic frequency of 3.50GHz, it seems that the turbo boost is not enabled.

But when I type `rdmsr -a 0x1A0 -f 38:38`, it gives me the output of 0 for all cores, which means that turbo boost IS actually enabled.

Am I using the wrong register here to read the turbo boost ON/OFF status?

I also tried `MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT` because this very CPU is Kaby Lake generation but how can I use turbo ratio limit to figure out if the turbo boost is enabled or not?

```
root@dse-seo-001:~> rdmsr -a 0x1AD
25262627
25262627
25262627
25262627
25262627
25262627
25262627
25262627
```